# How to find out broken links/ images throughout all the pages of a website using selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can find broken inks/ images in any particular webpage. But I am not able to find it throughout all the pages using Selenium. I have gone through many blogs but didn't find any code working. It would be great help if anyone one of you could help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 2):

Collect all the href attribute in your page using the 'a' and 'img' tagname in a list.

In java, iterate the loop,setup a HttpURLCOnnection for each url from the href list. Connect to it and check the response code. Google for logic and error codes responses.

Comment: Using HttpURLConnection, I can get the result of any particular page only. But I don't know how to check in each and every page. Can you please help? I believe the HttpURLConnection connection setup will be same for both the codes but I need the anchor tag of each and every page. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you will have to go to each page from which you want to check anchor tags.Then for each page you will have to send requests for each href you have. Please refer to the link that @Dev Raj has provided in answer above. BTW there are tools and websites which do this and much faster. Just google for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check broken images for all the pages, you can use HTTPClient library to check status codes of the images on a page.

First try to find all images on each page by using Webdriver.

**Below is the syntax:**

```
List<WebElement> imagesList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
```

**Below is the syntax to get links**

```
List<WebElement> anchorTagsList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

Now you need to iterate through each image and verify response code with HttpStatus.

You can find example from here [Find Broken / Invalid Images on a Page](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/find-broken-images-in-a-webpage-using-webdriver-java)

You can find example from here [Find Broken Links on a Page](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-find-broken-links-using-webdriver-java)

Comment: H Dev Raj- Using List, I can get all the Image links and I can check whether those are valid or invalid. Till that I am able to do. But I want to get broken links and images from each and every page of a website.Can you help?

Comment: @Selenium-learner, When response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200, you can get links/images.